# How to bind form template name from angular 6/8 component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8, mat-form-field

```
<form #userForm="ngForm"> </form>
```

Instead of writing userForm directly in Html i want to get this name from component like below

```
<form #{{formName}}="ngForm"> </form>
```

I would like to write in component like **this.formName = "userForm"**. but i am getting errors.

is there any way to fetch form template name from component?

Comment: `#{{formName}}` this  is wrong , you cannot set it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference of form. No, you can't. You can't create a variable for the reference. Just think,if you dynamically assign reference to form at runtime which is pointless and making mess to the whole application.